# SASS Concatenate class name?

Tags: sass, less

I got a LESS file from this [a Date-picker plugin](https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker) and want to convert it to SASS.

But in the LESS, it concates a class name like this:

```
//LESS
.dropdown{
    &-inline{
    }
}
```

Result:

```
.dropdown-inline ...
```

I tried many things in SASS like `#{-inline}` or `#{"-inline"}` but it doesn't work.

I tried googling and found a year-old article saying it's impossible in SASS. I can't found recent post about this issue. Is it possible now? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is not possible before version 3.2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sass-lang/1p6ucwepLxo) but [will be](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286) [eventually.](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/335) Just like LESS, the syntax will use `&`.

With updated scss, [you can now use the interpolation syntax `&--`](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-12) to DRY up your style files.

Answer (score 13):

Just moved from css to scss I ran in to this question and was disappointed until I found out it is not up-to-date.
Found the correct answer here: 
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-12.

It is now possible with the following syntax:

```
.add-some {
    &-red {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Results, as expected, to:

```
.add-some-red {
    color: red;
}
```