# Extend selector in SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using jQuery layout and I need to use these classes:

```
.ui-layout-button-pin, ui-layout-button-close {
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
}

.ui-layout-button-pin-east, .ui-layout-button-close-east {
    float: left;
}

.ui-layout-button-pin-west, .ui-layout-button-close-west {
    float: right;
}
```

#### Is there any way I can write the same code as above using sass?

I tried this, but couldn't get it to work:

```
.ui-layout-button-pin, ui-layout-button-close {
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    &-west { float:left; }
    &-east { float:right; }
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: tldr; SASS doesn't seem to support that (yet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16432215/3030434

Comment: I am looking for an intelligent work around. I know it's not possible exactly in the format as specified.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot do it because `SASS` does not support this feature at this moment.

Comment: I know that exact feature isn't supported yet, however is there a work around you would recommend?

Comment: Other than upgrading to an edge version of Sass, there is no work around.